# How to Merge multiple records from the concatenated column

Tags: sql, merge, concatenation, oracle-sqldeveloper, etl

I have multiple columns that has to be concatenate. I did it using a function. Next I need to merge multiple row into a single record separated by comma. I have a reference number (Sr#).

In the below image you can see how I concatenate the columns to a single column. we can see the duplicates in the row 4,5 and 6,7. I need help to understand how to merge those records with ref to sr#.

```
select Sr.sr#, a.created ||' // ' ||a.OWNERLASTNAME||' // ' ||a.OWNERFIRSTNAME||' // ' ||a.DESCRIPTION||' // ' ||a.activitystatus||' // ' ||a.ACTIVITYSUBSTATUS||' // ' ||a.closeddate as Dispatch_comments

From smaxtable
```

[image]
Please show me the solution to this. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly, you want to "concatenate" **distinct** values of `dispatch_comments` value. If that's so (presuming you're on Oracle, as you tagged the question with Oracle-SQLDeveloper tag), one option is to

- get distinct `dispatch_comments` values (which means you'll have to take only one, e.g. `MIN` value of `sr#`
- "concatenate" them using `listagg`. If resulting string exceeds 4000 characters, you'll need `xmlagg` instead

---

```
WITH your_query AS 
  (SELECT
        sr.sr#,
        a.created
        || ' // '
        || a.ownerlastname
        || ' // '
        || a.ownerfirstname
        || ' // '
        || a.description
        || ' // '
        || a.activitystatus
        || ' // '
        || a.activitysubstatus
        || ' // '
        || a.closeddate AS dispatch_comments
    FROM smaxtable
  ), 
temp AS 
  -- in order to get distinct DISPATCH_COMMENTS, take just one (e.g. MIN) sr#
  (SELECT MIN(sr#) sr#,
          dispatch_comments
    FROM your_query
    GROUP BY dispatch_comments
  )
-- finally, aggregate DISPATCH_COMMENTS
SELECT sr#,
       LISTAGG(dispatch_comments, ', ') WITHIN GROUP(ORDER BY NULL) result
FROM temp
GROUP BY sr#
```

Comment: Yes you're right I need to concatenate distinct values of dispatch_comments value with respect sr#. I don't understand this part WITH your_query AS. What does it mean.

Comment: That's a WITH factoring clause, also known as a CTE (Common Table Expression). We usually use it when we don't have actual tables in the database (because you didn't provide CREATE TABLE and INSERT INTO sample data, right?) in order to be able to show that query we wrote to help you actually *works*.